# Изменение цвета формы в JavaFX 8

Tags: java, gui, javafx

Есть такой вот код:

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Dipsach_v0.2");

    // Использовать панель поточной компоновки FlowPane в качестве корневого узла.
    // Установить промежутки мужду элементами управления по горизонтали и вертикали равными 10
    FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(10, 10);


    /* GUI-приложение - это театральной искусство */
    // Создать сцену
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 700, 500);

    // Установить сцену на подмостках
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    rootNode.getChildren().addAll(new DipsachTopMenuBar().getTopMenuBar());
    scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

В конце я указываю:

```
scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
```

Но цвет формы не меняется. Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: А если `Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 700, 500, Color.BLACK);`  поможет? .... А что прописано в `getTopMenuBar()` и конструкторе `DipsachTopMenuBar` ?  ибо, в принципе, то, что написано должно работать.. видимо что-то где перекрывается

Comment: Сделал - не помогло.

Comment: Я написал почему. Проверяйте другие места. Например закоментируйте `rootNode.getChildren().addAll(new DipsachTopMenuBar().getTopMenuBar());` ....будет видно фон?  наверняка что-то там прописано

Comment: Да, без добавления класса DipsachTopMenuBar все работает хорошо, но даже если добавлю new MenuBar() - все ломается. Что не так ?

Comment: Это надо смотреть как добавляете и что в коде прописано, лейауты, размеры. добавьте больше кода что там у вас где

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цвет сцены будет изменен если убрать весь контент с нее.
Сейчас он закрыт rootNode. Дабы исправить это пропишите данную строку!

```
rootNode.setStyle("-fx-backround-color: #000000");
```